# Wait for callback with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, callback

I am looking for a way to wait for the call back of a function before executing further in my program. This is something I have researched before and I have a couple little tricks I can show you first:

```
// You can wrap the rest of your code in the callback
/* executing code */
asyncFunction((err, callback)=>{
    if(err)console.log(err)
    else{
        /* The rest of your program */
    }
})

// You can do function chaining (use this to parallel asyncs)
var arr = newArray(2).fill(false)
asyncParallel()
function asyncParallel(){
    asyncFunction1((err,callback)=>{
        if(err)console.log(err)
        else{
            arr[arr.indexOf(false)] = true
            allDone()
        }
    }
    asyncFunction2((err, callback)=>{
        if(err)console.log(err)
        else{
            arr[arr.indexOf(false)] = true
            allDone()
        }
    }      
}
function allDone(){
    if(!arr.includes(false)){
       theRest()
    }
}
function theRest(){
    /* the rest of your code */
}

// You can wrap all of your code in a generator function
function* gen(){
    /* your code */
    yield something
    /* the rest of your code */
}
var g = gen()
g.next()
asyncFunction((err, callback)=>{
    if(err)console.log(err)
    else{
        g.next()
    }
}

//You could also download a fancy pants module which I have no time for
```

However, I am looking for a specific way of waiting for the callback. Basically I want an `axios.get` to fire and then my program only goes one step beyond that and hits a stopper and in the callback I want to release the stopper. It should look like this:

```
axios.get('myUrl').then(res=>{trigger()})
/* function to wait for trigger */
/* the rest of my code */
```

You may be tempted to put a while loop but this will stop any further code from executing:

```
var x = false
axios.get('myUrl').then(res=>{x = true})
while(x === false){
    // this will stop any other code from executing.
    // x will never be set to true.
}
```

Also, setting a timeout will not work in this instance because that itself is an async function and will not stop further code from executing (unless it is wrapped in a function which is called in the callback):

```
axios.get('myUrl').then(res=>{x = true})
setTimeout(/*I could put the code in here, but I don't want 
    to.*/, 10000)
/* code here will get executed before callbacks */
```

Is there a way to put a trigger in my callback and have a special non-code blocking function wait on that trigger before advancing any other code without having to wrap up all my code in another function? I am eagerly awaiting your answers and I hope this post helped people out!

Comment: Is `trigger` asynchronous and you want to wait for it to complete? If not, maybe I'm missing something, is just `await`ing the `axios` call at the point you want an option?

Comment: the "trigger()" I used in the example is merely a place holder for a way to release the hold that is waiting for the trigger. Also, `await` can only be called inside an async function. I would have to wrap all of my code inside the async function. I don't want to do this.

Comment: If you're dealing with Promises already, it really shouldn't be an issue, but if you don't want to, you can still use the old way and just call `.then` on the `Promise`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I would have to wrap the rest of my code in the `.then`. I am trying to avoid any wrapping.

Comment: There's no way around it, if you want the lower part to execute asynchronously from the upper part. Either wrap the lower part in a `.then`, or use `await` at the break point. Changing `function someFn() {` to `async function someFn() {` shouldn't be painful at all, I would think, especially if `someFn` is already dealing with `Promises`

Comment: My `axios.get` is inside a `for` loop. I need to make a lot of repeated and consecutive calls. The only way around it is to change it to a recursive function, I suppose :(

Comment: Not entirely sure because there isn't enough information, but you could probably use `reduce` instead, which is pretty functional. Might be able to come up with an answer if you posted your current `for` loop and described how you want the control flow to be.

Comment: I've already made the necessary changes. I can't reduce the array of urls because I need to make a call to every single one of them individually. Thanks for the offer though!